# Post keyboard event

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to post a keyboard event to trigger a Space change.

By default you can change Spaces with the control key + the number key for the space you wish to change to, here's the code I'm using but isn't working:

```
int spaceToChangeTo = 3;
int keyCodeForSpace = space + 17; // keycode 18 = number 1 on the keyboard, and onwards.

CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);

CGEventRef spaceDownEvent = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, (CGKeyCode)keyCodeForSpace, YES);
CGEventSetFlags(spaceDownEvent, kCGEventFlagMaskControl);

CGEventRef spaceUpEvent = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, (CGKeyCode)keyCodeForSpace, NO);

CGEventPost(kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, spaceDownEvent);
CGEventPost(kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, spaceUpEvent);

CFRelease(spaceDownEvent);
CFRelease(spaceUpEvent);
CFRelease(source);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, found the solution, where posting the event the correct code is:

```
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, spaceDownEvent);
```